# Power BI Matrix Visual Add Separator Line

Tags: powerbi

Power BI Matrix Visual:

How do you add a separator line in a matrix that has values set to switch values to rows?

Example:  Values are Revenues, Expenses, and Profit
Dates are columns (lined up at top of page)
Rev, exp, and Prof are in rows (aggregated)

how do I get a separator line between specific values?

if I have a value named 'Revenue' that is just a blank value and solely used for the header, how do I get a line under the entire row?  Goes across all dates?

I tried to add a "-" in the "Revenue" Value instead of blank, but that is not a solid line

Comment: Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77666868/edit) with a screen grab of what your matrix looks like and if possible, draw a line of where you are wanting the separator line. This will help us visualize your ask.